# Managing provisioning profiles in a team

Tags: app-store-connect, code-signing-certificate

So, I've got a part time job to maintain and upgrade an app, that was built not by me. Currently, I'm working from my team's the account.
Do I have to connect my developer account to this project? When I'm trying to upload a new build to Testflight, it shows the name of a previous developer as the author of a build (signing certificate) and it doesn't seem right.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about App provisioning and iTunesConnect, not directly programming related.

Comment: You should probably ask this question on [apple.stackexchange.com](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)